# How do I make "live streamed at launch" logical when that launch was canceled?

Tags: grammar

In [The event happened in the past. My interest is still there. "is" vs. "was"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/248823/115654) , I said

> SpaceX Demo-2 was scheduled for launch to the International Space Station on 27 May 2020. **NASA live streamed at launch.** I off work early to specifically watch that. When I got home, I found that the launch was canceled, which made me a little bit upset. But the whole thing is interesting.

I guess "NASA live streamed at launch" is grammatically correct but illogical, as that launch was postponed, so NASA didn't actually live stream that launch. However, NASA did live stream the preparation for over 7 hours and that cancelation.

How do I make it logical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It was to be live-streamed by NASA at launch."

That expresses that the plan was for NASA to live stream it.
You might also put it like this

> "It would have been live-streamed at launch, if it hadn't been canceled."

or

> "NASA live-streamed the preparation, right up until the launch was canceled."

You could also delay that information until after you tell how you discovered the launch was canceled.